# Вернуть правильное значение Content-Length при HEAD запросе к WCF службе

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf, http-заголовки

Есть self-hosted WCF служба со следующим контрактом:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "HEAD", UriTemplate = "Files/{fileName}")]
    void GetFileInfo(string fileName);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Files/{fileName}")]
    Stream StreamFile(string fileName);
}
```

Упрощённая реализация её такова:

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void GetFileInfo(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine("Files", fileName);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        var response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.ContentLength = fi.Length;
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    }

    public Stream StreamFile(string fileName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Проблема в методе `GetFileInfo`. Когда происходит HEAD запрос к службе (например, с помощью `WebRequest`):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/MyService/Files/test.dat");
var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "HEAD";
using (var resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
    foreach (string header in resp.Headers)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", header, resp.Headers[header]);
}
```

то в ответ приходит:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1234
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2016 10:17:38 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

но это в случае, если длина запрашиваемого файла не превышает `int.MaxValue`. Если же длина файла превышает `int.MaxValue` то `Content-Length` в ответе имеет значение 0:

```
Content-Length: 0
```

Как это победить? Как заставить возвращать нормальную длину для больших файлов?

Конфигурация WCF-службы (если это важно):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="be_webHttpStreamed">
        <webHttp  />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="WCFTestService.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpStreamed" behaviorConfiguration="be_webHttpStreamed" contract="WCFTestService.IMyService" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpStreamed" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что это ошибка в коде `System.ServiceModel`, а конкретно - вот в этом [участке](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelHelpers.cs,2992). Интересно то, что проблема сохраняется и при хостинге сервиса в IIS.

Как вариант исправления - создать кастомный байндинг, наследующий от `WebHttpBinding`, с [кастомным transport channel](http://www.dotnet-geek.co.uk/index.php/creating-wcf-custom-transport-channel/), и в нем организовать правильную расстановку заголовков у `HttpListener` (этот класс используется при self-хостинге сервисов с http-транспортом).

IMHO, это неоправданно сложно. Проще пойти на нарушение принципов RESTful-архитектуры и сделать запрос размера файла через POST с результатом в теле ответа. Или отправлять длину в другом заголовке.

---

Проблемные [участки кода](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelHelpers.cs,2988):

```
// HttpChannelHelpers.cs, line 2988
if (string.Compare(name, "content-length", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
    int contentLength = -1;
    if (httpMethodIsHead &&
        int.TryParse(value, out contentLength))
    {
        this.SetContentLength(contentLength);
    }
    // else
    //this will be taken care of by System.Net when we write to the content
}
```

и

```
// HttpChannelHelpers.cs, line 3061
protected override void SetContentLength(int contentLength)
{
    listenerResponse.ContentLength64 = contentLength;
}
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, а проблема в ответе сервера? Сервер принципиально больше не способен отдать или это клиент не умеет больше считывать?

Comment: @Monk да, сервер не может отдать больше. Посмотрите по первой ссылке реализацию SetContentLength.

Comment: Может быть, это и не ошибка, и размер органичен сознательно. Только мне не ясно, почему.

Comment: Размер ограничен прям на базовом уровне - SetContentLengh принимает int. Тогда видать хватало всем 2гб.

Comment: @Monk Как я понял, Content-Length выставляется только при HEAD-запросе явно, потому что HttpListener не может поставить ее автоматом - тела у ответа нет. Во всех остальных случаях он проставит длину сам. Но почему используется int, тогда как `HttpListener.ContentLength64` - long... Причем в .NET 3.5 уже был long.

Comment: Жаль, но клиентская часть мне не подвластна. Код в вопросе, делающий HEAD запрос - имитация. На самом деле его делает BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service). Он сначала делает HEAD, чтобы понять размер ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362846.aspx)), и если возвращается 0, то файл не скачивает. Так то я придумал как его обмануть, но получается костыль и не универсально. В общем, буду думать как поступить. То ли оставить костыль, то ли отказаться от BITS, то ли выкладывать файл в директорию IIS (он нормально отдаёт Content-Length в ответ на HEAD).

Comment: @kmv: Хм. Похоже на баг. Может быть, запостите им багрепорт? https://github.com/dotnet/wcf // Update: Странно, не могу найти этот класс в репозитории — уже пофиксили или переписали заново?

Comment: @VladD Это репозиторий с клиентом для .net core, баги к "взрослому" .net, похоже, нужно отправлять [сюда](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio). Я правда, языками не владею :(

Comment: Да, надо бы написать на Connect. Давайте я напишу. Может быть включите в ответ куски кода, чтобы можно было дать ссылку на ответ. По-русски конечно не поймут, но код думаю поймут. Предлагаю два куска вставить. Вот этот `if (string.Compare(name, "content-length", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) { ... }` со всем, что внутри фигурных скобок, и метод `SetContentLength` c его содержимым.

Comment: Отправил, [Feedback ID 2864692](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2864692).